# How to add image to a table column in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I am creating table with AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable. I want to add image to each column and when user clicks any column for sorting, I want to change this image.

Is this is possible?

Comment: Are these images to be in the column header?

Comment: @donroby: Yes that is correct. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best handled by css.

If you look at [this example of an AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.AjaxDataTablePage), you'll note that with no work at all, the headers change background color when clicked.

This happens because of wicket-defined css classes "wicket_orderUp", "wicket_orderDown", and "wicket_orderNone" on the header set by the callbacks when you click on columns, and some default css supplied by wicket.

If you create css that sets a background image for these classes, possibly qualified by other css hierarchy if you don't want it everywhere, you should be able to get changing images with no Java code.

Comment: You are right, I am able to add images now to the header. I have added .wicket_orderUp, .wicket_orderDown, .wicket_orderNone properties in my own css file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have another question, If I want to make the complete column header as clickable, how do I do that. That is, currently it supports only clicking on column name, but I want to have option to click anywhere on that table column header for sorting. I will post new question for this.